# How to properly configure meson / ninja / qt creator for recent c++ version?

Tags: c++, qt, smart-pointers, ninja, meson-build

I have tried to run a code which uses smart pointers recently. As the title says, I use Ninja (version 1.10.2), Meson (0.57.2) and Qt Creator 4.14.2.
I have the following meson.build :

```
project('RayTracerDemo',
    'cpp',
    version: '0.0.0',
    default_options: [
        'c_std=c2x',
        'cpp_std=c++20',
        'warning_level=3',
        'optimization=3',
        'werror=true'
    ]
)

includeDir = include_directories([])

sources = files([
    'main.cpp'
])

headers = files([])

raytracer_exe = executable(
    'RayTracerDemo',
    sources: sources + headers,
    include_directories: includeDir,
    dependencies: []
)
```

But I still get the following error :

```cpp
/~/programs/RayTracerDemo/main.cpp:189: error: ‘make_unique’ is not a member of ‘std’
../main.cpp: In function ‘void render(const std::vector<Sphere>&)’:
../main.cpp:189:52: error: ‘make_unique’ is not a member of ‘std’
  189 |             threads[height * width + width] = std::make_unique<std::thread>([&]() -> void
      |                                                    ^~~~~~~~~~~
../main.cpp:189:52: note: ‘std::make_unique’ is only available from C++14 onwards
```

for the following lines :

```cpp
threads[height * width + width] = std::make_unique<std::thread>([&]() -> void
{
    float xx = (2 * ((x + 0.5) * invWidth) - 1) * angle * aspectratio;
    float yy = (1 - 2 * ((y + 0.5) * invHeight)) * angle;
    Vec3f raydir(xx, yy, -1);
    raydir.normalize();
    *pixel = trace(Vec3f(0), raydir, spheres, 0);
});
```

threads being a vector declared like so:

```cpp
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<std::thread>> threads(height * width);
```

Qt Creator documentation says that some features aren't supported using Meson [here](https://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-project-meson.html#current-meson-support-limitations), but this does not include compiler version issues.

Comment: What is your compile and its version? What if you use cpp_std=c++14 ?

Comment: I have g++ (GCC) 10.2.0, and I already have tried every possible version above c++14, including it.

Answer (score 1):

It looks that everything is OK with meson options, you just forgot to add **< memory>** header (yes, error message is a bit confusing):

```
#include <memory>
...
```

Also, it could be due to setting **c_std** option for C++ compiler, since this option is for C compiler.

It's also possible that build directory is not (re)configured properly. To check currently configured options and flags you can with:

```
$ meson configure <build dir>
```

And to reconfigure:

```
$ meson setup --reconfigure <build dir>
```

BTW (it't nor related to question), this looks strange:

```
threads[height * width + width]  =
```

as it overlaps the vector, shouldn't it be ? :

```
threads[invHeight * width + invWidth]  =
```

## **TL;DR**

This basic code :

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World!" << std::endl;
    std::unique_ptr<int> a = std::make_unique<int>();
    return 0;
}
```

will not work. Compiler tells me C++ 14 or plus is required to use make_unique. The issue is that I already put "project('ThreadPool', 'cpp', default_options : ['cpp_std=c++17'])" in the meson.build file, but for some reason this file is just not taken in account by Qt Creator : checking what are the build settings, the C++ version chosen is C++11.

Comment: I included memory, already. And if Im not wrong, accessing a one dimension array as if it was a two dimensional array is : `array[y * x + x % y]` ?
Edit : Im completely wrong.
Edit2 : My for loop was messy, thank you for noticing, it was indeed not what I had put but `threads[y * width + x]` instead.

Comment: @Bebel ok, so, have you solved build error?

Comment: Unfortunately, no ! I still get the same error. Im sure it comes from meson / ninja / qt creator, because when I compile from command line it works (I still get a different error but that is because my code is wrong).

Comment: @Bebel try removing c_std option setting

Comment: I changed my code, so I kind of can't get back and retry, but I the c_std option wasn't there a few hours ago, and I still had the same issue.

Comment: @Bebel then you could check all compiler flags with $ meson introspect --targets build/

Comment: @Babel check also if you (re)configured build directory correctly $ meson configure <build dir>  <---- it will show you flags and options, including cpp_std - what does it show? Try also $ meson setup --reconfigure <build dir>

Comment: Thanks for answering, and sorry for being late answering back ! So, as expected, the compiler version flag is the wrong one :
`..."-fdiagnostics-color=always", "-pipe", "-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64", "-Wall", "-Winvalid-pch", "-Wnon-virtual-dtor", "-std=c++11", "-g", "-pthread"],  ...`

Comment: I am going to edit my issue to make it more clear, since I have brought out the source of the problem. (Ill add a TL;DR section)

Comment: @Babel, ok, I see, I have never worked with Qt creator, but following your link I came to https://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-build-settings-meson.html - have you tried this panel, do you see there smth like cpp_std ?